# Returning String of joined certain fields from objects in HashSet

Tags: java, string, join, return, hashset

I'm trying to write getter for a HashSet, where Object contains multiple attributes of Strings and Integers. 
Getter should return joined String of only two of the String fields, separated with coma, for every object that is stored in HashSet.

I could write it using loops and that way its not hard, but I'd like to find shorter, more elegant and clever solution. 
I tried with the String.join(), but it doesn't accept HashSet of Objects.
Using Object.toString() is not an option, because toString() should return more Object's attributes, while this getter should return only two of them.

Lets imagine simplified library with Book object and Borrower object, where every Book borrowed by Borrower is stored in HashSet in Borrower object.

```
import java.util.HashSet;

public class Main{

    public static void main(String []args){

        Borrower john = new Borrower("John");

        Book book1 = new Book("Title1", "Author1", "Isbn1", 100);
        Book book2 = new Book("Title2", "Author2", "Isbn2", 200);
        Book book3 = new Book("Title3", "Author3", "Isbn3", 300);

        john.borrowBook(book1);
        john.borrowBook(book2);
        john.borrowBook(book3);
        System.out.println(john.getBorrowed()); 
            // It should print 
                // Title1, Author1
                // Title2, Author2
                // Title3, Author3     
       }
}

class Book {
    String title;
    String author;
    String isbn;
    int pageNum;

    Book(String t, String a, String i, int p){
        this.title = t;
        this.author = a;
        this.isbn = i;
        this.pageNum = p;
    }

    public String getAuthor() { return author;  }
    public String getTitle() {  return title;   }
}

class Borrower {
    String name;
    HashSet <Book> onLoan = new HashSet<Book>();

    Borrower(String n){
        this.name = n;
    }

    public boolean borrowBook(Book b) {
        return onLoan.add(b);
    }

    public String getBorrowed(){

        if(onLoan.isEmpty())
            return "No books borrowed";
        else{
            // It should return joined string of only title and author for every book in HashSet, 
            //title and author separated with coma, each object in new line, like "title, author \n"
            return "---";   
        }
    }
}
```

Borrower's getBorrowed() should return joined String of only title and author for every book in HashSet.

Comment: Why not override `toString()` in `Book` to return what you want?

Comment: Because I need full content toString() to something else, and writing completely new method is not as elegant solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple solution using streams:

```
public String getBorrowed(){

        if(onLoan.isEmpty())
            return "No books borrowed";
        else{
            return onLoan.stream().map(b -> b.getTitle() + ", " + b.getAuthor()).collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
Title3, Author3
Title2, Author2
Title1, Author1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Java 8 stream api and a combination of map and reduce methods.

Here's my solution:

```
String output = onLoan.stream()
     .map(book -> book.getTitle() + ", " + book.getAuthor())
     .reduce("", (value, current) -> value + "\n" + current);
```

It's a HashSet so the order of output may not follow the order of addition.